# Android FTPUpload Progress Bar

Tags: android, ftp, android-progressbar

I'm using the **org.apache.commons.net.ftp** [FTPClient class] to upload some directories that are created when the user take pictures. However, I couldn't show a progress bar to demonstrate that action.

I made a new thread to call it as below:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        String server = "IP";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "USER";
        String pass = "PASSWORD";

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

        try {
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);

            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            String remoteDirPath = "/";
            String localDirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/PicturesAPP/";
            FTPUtil.uploadDirectory(ftpClient, remoteDirPath, localDirPath, "");
            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

I tried to call inside of it a progress dialog, but it not show up.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an AsyncTask:

```
    private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
              private ProgressDialog pDialog;
              String server = "IP";
              int port = 21;
              String user = "USER";
              String pass = "PASSWORD";

            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    pDialog.show();

                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                  try {
                     ftpClient.connect(server, port);
                     ftpClient.login(user, pass);

                     ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                     String remoteDirPath = "/";
                     String localDirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/PicturesAPP/";
                     FTPUtil.uploadDirectory(ftpClient, remoteDirPath, localDirPath, "");
                     ftpClient.logout();
                     ftpClient.disconnect();

                  } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                  }
               }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                 pDialog.dismiss();
               }
        }
```

Then:

```
 new YourAsyncTask().execute();
```